# オブジェクトの色の変更

Tags: c#, unity3d

ある処理でfalseの場合（そのボタンが使えないことを意味する）に、ボタンの色をデフォルトの色ではない色に変更をしたい（そのボタンが使えないと視覚でわかるようにするため）のですが、Unityにおいてスクリプトで実現する方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

```
Button.colors.disabledColor
```

こちらに動的なボタンカラーへのアクセスがあります。

サンプル：http://docs.unity3d.com/jp/current/ScriptReference/UI.ColorBlock-disabledColor.html